# Aerospike HDD/Memory usage

Tags: memory-management, aerospike

I'm exploring Aerospike as key-value DB with storing data on disk for safety. Please confirm, that I understand this correctly:

---

1. If in namespace configuration I set:

   - storage-engine **device**
   - memory-size 4G
   - file /opt/aerospike/data/namespace.dat
   - filesize 16G
   - data-in-memory **false**

`->` all data will be on disk only, "memory-size" is for indexes only (small usage), all data will be stored in multiple 16GB files (which will be creating automatically), and most important - every `read` query will trigger reading data from disk?

---

2. If in namespace configuration I set:

   - storage-engine **device**
   - memory-size 4G
   - file /opt/aerospike/data/namespace.dat
   - filesize 16G
   - data-in-memory **true**

`->` all data will be on disk and partly in memory, "memory-size" will act like cache and contain 4GB of most used data, all data will be stored in multiple 16GB files (which will be creating automatically), and most important - every `read` query will trigger checking data from memory and if missing -> reading from disk and adding to memory? What data will be in memory - most used or latest created?

---

3. If in namespace configuration I set:

   - storage-engine **memory**
   - memory-size 4G
   - data-in-memory **true**

`->` all data will be in memory only, I'm limited to 4GB of data and no more?

Comment: Curious about how on (2) you came to the conclusion that 16GB files "will be creating automatically," as you aren't the first to deduce this incorrectly. Is there a piece of documentation that needs attention?

Comment: @kporter, docs say `Max size of each file in GiB` - this is a setting for specific namespace. So it affects 1 namespace only, and it would be extremely strange if we had to create DB files manually

Comment: You had also stated that it will be stored in "multiple files" but only specified a single file. I took this to mean that you had determined that when Aerospike fills up the file you specified it would generate a new file automatically. **This is not the case**, you need to specify each file you want Aerospike to use/create - your current configuration will limit you to a single 16 GiB file.

Comment: @kporter, thanks. I was wrong then, I really was thinking new file will be created when the first one is full. Something like `filename_1`, `filename_2` etc. When I get more than 16GB of data - what will happen with newest entries? Will they overwrite the oldest? How do I know when the file is close to be full?

Comment: Storage is actively defraged. Aerospike offers training courses: http://www.aerospike.com/schedule/. For this topic I suggest reading http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/manage/storage and https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/defragmentation/718.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aerospike doesn't shuffle data in and out of disk like first generation NoSQL databases do, ones that have a "cache-first" architecture. Aerospike's [hybrid memory architecture](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/storage.html) is such that the [primary index](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/primary-index.html) (metadata) is *always* in memory. Depending on the namespace configuration, the data is stored *fully* on disk or in memory. You define storage for each namespace. If it is in-memory all the data and metadata is in-memory, fully. if the namespace stores its data on a few devices (/dev/sdb, /dev/sdc) the primary index (metadata) is fully in memory and the data is fully on those SSDs.

(1) is data on HDD, and the configuration is correct. If you're using an SSD you probably want to use `device` instead of `file`. One thing that isn't true in your question is that Aerospike will first check the [`post-write-queue`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#post-write-queue) on a read.

Aerospike does [block writes](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/faq-write-block-size/681) to optimize around the high-read / low-write performance of HDD and SSD. The size of the block is determined by the [`write-block-size`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration#write-block-size) config parameter (should be 1MB for a HDD). The records are first loaded into a streaming write buffer of an equivalent size. After the buffer is flushed to a block on disk, Aerospike doesn't get rid of this in-memory copy immediately; it remains part of the post-write queue (FIFO). By default, 256 of those blocks are in the queue per-device, or per-file (you can define multiple `file` lines as the storage device). If your usage pattern is such that reads follow closely after the writes, you'll be getting in-memory access instead of disk access. If your [`cache_read_pct`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/metrics#cache_read_pct) metric is not single digits and you have DRAM to spare, you probably can benefit from raising the `post-write-queue` value (max of 2048 blocks per-device).

(2) is an in-memory namespace, persisted to disk. For both (1) and (2) you can use either `file` (for filesystem based storage) or `device` (for raw device). Both the primary index (metadata) and storage (data) are in memory for (2).  All reads and writes come out of memory, and a secondary write-through goes to the persistence device.

[`filesize`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration#filesize) reserves the size of the persistence layer on the filesystem (if you chose to use `file` and not `device`). You can have multiple `file` lines, each of which will be sized from the start to the number given as `filesize`. [`memory-size`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration#memory-size) is the maximum amount of memory used by the namespace. This isn't pre-reserved. Aerospike will grow and shrink in memory usage over time, with the maximum for the namespace being its `memory-size`.

Take a look at [What's New in 3.11](http://www.aerospike.com/blog/whats-new-in-aerospike-3-11/), specifically the section that touches on in-memory performance improvements. Tuning [`partition-tree-sprigs`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration#partition-tree-sprigs) and [`partition-tree-locks`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration#partition-tree-sprigs) will likely boost the performance of your in-memory namespaces.

(3) is a purely in-memory namespace, usually intended to be a cache. The 4G limit affects things such as [`stop-writes-pct`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration#stop-writes-pct), [`high-water-memory-pct`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration#high-water-memory-pct) as those are defined as a percentage of that limit (see [evictions, expirations, stop-writes](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/faq-what-are-expiration-eviction-and-stop-writes/2311)).

There's also a (4) special-case for counters called data-in-index. See [storage engine configuration recipes](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/namespace/storage).

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer! Some questions left:
`(1)` Is "filesize" a limit to the total DB data size or this is for 1 file only and there will be more of them created automatically? I'll mostly read the data, so between reads and writes can be weeks and more - so data mostly will be read directly from disk?

`(2)` Every read query will trigger checking data from memory and if missing -> reading from disk and adding to RAM? What data will be in memory - latest used or latest created?

`(3)` So that's true - I can have only 4GB of data for this namespace?

Comment: 1. "Filesize" will be the size of _each_ file that gets created. Your DB's total data limit is "Filesize" * Number of files/devices * cluster size / replication factor. That's before factoring in high water mark and stop-writes. Our balancing algorithm does a decent job of balancing records/partitions so there's no real point in multiple files if on the same device.
2. Every read will read from memory. Every write will write to both memory and disk. 
3. 4GB, _per node_.

Comment: `4` Files with "filesize" and path will be created/balanced automatically on each node?

`5` With **data-in-memory false** will every read-query trigger a reading directly from disk? (write operation was long time ago).

`6` With **data-in-memory true** what data will be in memory - latest used or latest created? You can't write all data in RAM with 4GB limit, most of data will be dropped.

Comment: (4) Yes, the config is for the local node, and it applies `file` lines to the node. (5) Unless it first finds it in the `post-write-queue`, as I explained above. (6) ALL the data will be in memory. The entire primary index, and all the data for all the records. Data is not dropped as you start filling the `memory-size` - you will first hit `stop-write` and the database will go into read-only mode until evictions make room.

Comment: @RonenBotzer, Thanks. In (6) what will happen if data is always coming in? `high-water-memory-pct` value is 60% - it will force to rewrite oldest data with the newest? `stop-writes-pct` value is 90% - it will be activated much more later

Comment: @RonenBotzer, probably I've got it - stored data **with TTL** will be deleted (oldest) to free space. Stored data **without TTL** will continue to append until 90% - then client on a write request will get an error. Am I right?

Comment: You're right. When the water marks are breached evictions will kick in, and the records with the nearest TTL will be removed. However, if all the records have TTL 0, nothing can be evicted, and the data will continue to pile up until you hit stop-writes. This is explained in the FAQ I mention near the bottom. You always need to do capacity planning taking into account a node going down. You can select this answer as the correct one, if it is. :)

Comment: @RonenBotzer, last question - in section (2) I have **memory-size 4G** and **filesize 16G** - is this normal? I mean if my limit is 4GB of memory and no more -> there is no need to set 16GB (more than 4GB) for disk usage, because only 4GB can be used?!

Comment: You would be leaving 50% of SSD empty for defragmentation, so if you're storing on `device /dev/sdb` (for example) you'd need a partition that is 8G for the `memory-size 4G`. If you're persisting to the filesystem we recommend a 4x value, rather than the 2x of the SSD.

Comment: @RonenBotzer, the same for HDD?

Comment: Look at my comment above. If you had a namespace `memory-size` of 4G, for `device` you would allocate an 8G partition. That does not have `filesize` apply. For HDD you would declare a 16G `filesize`. Are we done here?